# orderby not working to get top 1 result in subquery using LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

i am trying to get top 1 result from child table using sub query. When i try to use `orderby or OrderByDescending` using sub query it throws

> NullReferenceException

. Without using `orderby or OrderByDescending` my query execute successfully.
But i want to get last record for sub query. my app is connected with Mysql database.

my code is give below

```
var result = (from ud in db.user_devices
                          join a in db.access_info on ud.u_id equals a.u_id
                          join d in db.device_num on ud.dev_id equals d.DevId
                          //let pi = db.packet_info.Where(x =>  x.DevId == ud.dev_id && x.DevId != null).OrderByDescending(x =>x.systime).FirstOrDefault()
                          //where  pi != null
                          select new
                          {
                              fuel = db.packet_info.Where(x => x.DevId == ud.dev_id).OrderByDescending(x => x.systime).Select(x => x.fuel).FirstOrDefault(),
                              //removed other fields
                          }).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you please provide definition of db.packet_info or at least type of property systime?

Comment: its datatype is timestamp in mysql and DateTime in C#

Comment: Is there a chance you have nulls in systime?

Comment: there is no null value.. i have checked..

Answer (score 0):

Used an alternative way, Created a procedure with same schema as linq.

Procedure code is given below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`abc`@`%` PROCEDURE `spGetAllVechiles`()
BEGIN
    SELECT 

       (SELECT g.fuel  FROM abc.Packet_Info AS g WHERE g.devid = ud.dev_id order by systime desc LIMIT 0,1 ) AS fuel,
       (SELECT  g.fencealarm FROM abc.Packet_Info AS g WHERE g.devid = ud.dev_id order by systime desc LIMIT 0,1 ) AS fencealarm,
       (SELECT  g.speed  FROM abc.Packet_Info AS g WHERE g.devid = ud.dev_id order by systime desc LIMIT 0,1 ) AS speed,
       (SELECT  g.Latitude FROM abc.Packet_Info AS g WHERE g.devid = ud.dev_id order by systime desc LIMIT 0,1 ) AS Latitude,
       (SELECT  g.Longitude FROM abc.Packet_Info AS g WHERE g.devid = ud.dev_id order by systime desc LIMIT 0,1 ) AS Longitude
       //other params...

    FROM abc.access_info AS ac 
    INNER JOIN abc.user_devices AS ud ON ud.u_id = ac.u_id
    INNER JOIN abc.device_num AS dn ON dn.DevId = ud.dev_id;
```